# management.tracing.sampling.probability not showing up in my microservices project. I'm using micrometer and webclient. how do i fix this?

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

so, I can use the property management.tracing.sampling.probability in my discovery server. But in my microservices classes i can't see or use the property in my yaml file. I've tried like every dependency possible. but I don't understand how i can only use and see it in my discovery server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is Boot 3.x, if so you need Actuator and a bridge:

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'